# How to solve the equation $x^2+2=4\sqrt{x^3+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

From the Leningrad Mathematical Olympiad, 1975:

> Solve $x^2+2=4\sqrt{x^3+1}$.

In answer sheet only written $x=4+2\sqrt{3}\pm \sqrt{34+20\sqrt{3}}$.

How to solve this?

Comment: @VonNeumann . i'm sorry . I edited

Comment: **Hint:** Square both sides, simplify, rinse and repeat.

Comment: @Moo It's not easy

Comment: Does it need to be easy?

Comment: I don't see how to reach the solution but the solution, if correct, looks like a quadratic formula applied to a quartic.

Comment: @Almot1960 It is easy once you notice $x^3 + 1 = (x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ and $(x+1) + (x^2-x+1) = x^2+2$.

Answer (score 9):

Let $u = x^2-x+1$, $v = x+1$  and $\lambda = \sqrt{\frac{u}{v}}$, we have

$$\begin{align}u + v & = (x^2-x+1) + (x + 1) = x^2 + 2 \\ &= 4\sqrt{x^3+1} = 4\sqrt{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}\\ &= 4\sqrt{uv}\end{align}$$
This leads to

$$\lambda^2 + 1 = 4\lambda \implies \lambda = 2 \color{red}{\pm} \sqrt{3}$$
As a result,
$$\begin{align} &x^2 - x + 1 = \lambda^2 (x+1) = (7\color{red}{\pm} 4\sqrt{3})(x+1)\\
\iff & x^2 - (8 \color{red}{\pm} 4\sqrt{3})x  = (6\color{red}{\pm} 4\sqrt{3})\\
\iff & (x - (4 \color{red}{\pm} 2\sqrt{3}))^2  = (4 \color{red}{\pm} 2\sqrt{3})^2 + (6 \color{red}{\pm} 4\sqrt{3})
= 34 \color{red}{\pm} 20\sqrt{3}\\
\implies & x = 4 \color{red}{\pm} 2\sqrt{3} \color{blue}{\pm} \sqrt{34 \color{red}{\pm} 20\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}$$
Notice $34-20\sqrt{3} \approx -0.651 < 0$. For real $x$, 
the red $\color{red}{\pm}$ sign need to be $+$. This leaves us with

$$x = 4 + 2\sqrt{3} \color{blue}{\pm} \sqrt{34 + 20\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: This is the right solution. Very nice.

Answer (score 3):

I think the "fastest" way to deal with this is surely to square both members, to get

$$x^4 -16x^3 +4x^2 - 12 = 0$$

Now you can treat is as the quartic equation it is, via Ferrari's method for quartic equations.

I will write you down the general procedure for a quartic of the form

$$ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0$$

And leave you the easy maths behind.

**Define the following quantities**

$$P = 8ac - 3b^2$$

$$Q = b^3 + 8da - 4abc$$

$$R = c^2 - 3bd + 12 ae$$

$$S = 64a^3e - 16a^2c^2 + 16ab^2c - 16 a^2bd - 3b^4$$

**Define other elements**

$$U = \frac{P}{8a^2}$$

$$V = \frac{Q}{8a^3}$$

$$Y = 2c^3 - 9bcd + 27b^2e - 27ad^2 - 27ace$$

$$Z = \sqrt[3]{\frac{Y + \sqrt{Y^2 - 4R^2}}{2}}$$

$$W = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{2U}{3} + \frac{1}{3a} \left( Z + \frac{R}{Z}\right) }$$

**Final Solutions (note: only two of them will be real, in your case)**

$$x_{1,\ 2} = -\frac{b}{4a} - W \pm \sqrt{-4W^2 - 2U + \frac{V}{W}}$$

$$x_{3,\ 4} = -\frac{b}{4a} + W \pm \sqrt{-4W^2 - 2U - \frac{V}{W}}$$

**NOTICE** In your case $\color{red}{d = 0}$ which simplifies a bit the resolvent.

Comment: ok and you have all these formulas in your head?

Comment: my great respect for you, nomen est omen dear von Neumann

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Well you know, when you have fun with maths despite other people's mocks since a child... Things you remember, things you use.. "Nomen est omen", I wish I were like him!! Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I remember two cubic formulae. The first one solving for $x$ in the equation, $x^3 + cx = d$ and the other in $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$. I have never seen this before, so I will remember this one :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-The given answer is root of the quadratic equation
$$x^2-2(4+2\sqrt3)x+c=0$$ where $c$ is certain constant. It follows 
$$x=4+2\sqrt3\pm\sqrt{{(4+2\sqrt3)^2-c}}=4+2\sqrt3\pm\sqrt{34+20\sqrt3}$$
You get so the value of $c$ from which you can verify the solution.